# Sorting array of object multiple times result in weird bug in browser console | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of object like this:

```
let guests = [{name: 'a'},{name: 'c'},{name: 'b'}]
```

I am experimenting to sort it by descending and then ascending order:

```js
let guests = [{
  name: 'a'
}, {
  name: 'c'
}, {
  name: 'b'
}]
console.log(guests)

var var1 = guests.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name)
console.log(var1)

var var2 = guests.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name)
console.log(var2)
```

The result for all three console is this:

```
[{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]
```

What I don't understand is why all three console.log will show me the one sorted in ascending order. Two of the console.log happen before the sorting occur.

Now I do understand that the array is manipulated after sort. But what I don't understand is why would the console.log before the sort be affected. To compare to a normal behavior which I expect, I used a array of string.

```
let guests = ['a','c','b']
```

jsfiddle example: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/pru6ywsb/3/)
The console.log here makes more sense to me.

Comment: Take a look on sort method. You must return `1`,`0` or `-1`

Comment: it works like a charm chrome's console. I think cause of bug is jsfiddle not javascript.

Comment: log shows ["a", "c", "b"], ["c", "b", "a"] and ["c", "b", "a"] respectively

Comment: @Alexis I think it is not because of -1, 0, 1. I modified the jsFiddle example and it is the same. https://jsfiddle.net/7vs8ft0a/14/

Comment: @BerkAkkerman It is not jsfiddle, I tested on a javascript file in my C# mvc app. It has the same behaviour

Comment: @kamp what you see is the second jsFiddle with the expected behaviour. The jsFiddle is the one with a weird behaviour.

Comment: oh I see. It's because var1 and var2 are just a reference to the original array which is guests that's why the console are all the same

Comment: But how come in my second jsFiddle example, the array are not the same? In fact, i think the second jsFiddle example is the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, despite Array.sort() returns an array it is only a reference so it affects the original array instead of a copy (in-place algorithm).
In order to obtain a new array you have to clone the array (slice, lodash deepClone, etc) before sort in.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Important line in doc:

> The sorted array. Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made.

**Working example:**

```js
let guests = [{
  name: 'a'
}, {
  name: 'c'
}, {
  name: 'b'
}]
console.log(guests)

var var1 = guests.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name)
console.log(var1)

var var2 = guests.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name)
console.log(var2)
```

**Note**

*console.log* implementation differs from browser to browser, and you can't rely on it when mutating directly objects because the fetch of the object itself maybe async.

**Note 2**

Also *var* statement is part of the issue beacause of hoisting:

> var declarations, wherever they occur, are processed before any code is executed. This is called hoisting, and is discussed further below.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description

Comment: I understand it manipulate the original array. But it should only manipulate it after the sort right? My second jsFiddle example proof that.

Comment: console.log (in chrome and in other browser) is not executed immediately

Comment: for example when sorting objects the fetch of the object is done async when the object is unfolded in console.

Comment: After some experimentation, I realized this is indeed a behaviour of console.log of browser. This jsfiddle example show it. https://jsfiddle.net/7vs8ft0a/19/. I think when it is an array of object, the console will display [object, object, object]. And only after the execution, the browser will look for the value of object and inject it in. Your note is actually the correct answer, can you put it above your other response and i will mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are modifying one array therefore all console logs get affected.

What you are doing is just setting var1 and var2 as a reference to guests.

If you want to see separate results then you need a new copy of that array. You can do a .slice(0) of the original array.

```
let guests = [{name: 'a'},{name: 'c'},{name: 'b'}]
console.log(guests)

var var1 = guests.slice(0).sort((a,b)=> a.name<b.name ? 1:-1)
console.log(var1)

var var2 = guests.slice(0).sort((a,b)=> a.name>b.name ? 1:-1)
console.log(var2)
```

Comment: I know modification of array will affect all reference to it. But i don't understand how it can affect a console.log that is before the modification. As contrast, look at my second jsfiddle link where the console.log is showing properly.